# Extract text between single quotes in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab, quotes

I have multiple lines in some text files such as

```
.model sdata1 s tstonefile='../data/s_element/isdimm_rcv_via_2port_via_minstub.s50p' passive=2
```

I want to extract the text between the single quotes in MATLAB.

Much help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all of the text inside multiple `''` blocks, regexp can be used as follows:

```
regexp(txt,'''(.[^'']*)''','tokens')
```

This says to get text surrounded by `'` characters, which does not include a `'` in the captured text.  For example, consider this file with two lines (I made up different file name),

```
txt = ['.model sdata1 s tstonefile=''../data/s_element/isdimm_rcv_via_2port_via_minstub.s50p'' passive=2 ', char(10), ...
'.model sdata1 s tstonefile=''../data/s_element/isdimm_rcv_via_3port_via_minstub.s00p'' passive=2']
>> stringCell = regexp(txt,'''(.[^'']*)''','tokens');
>> stringCell{:}
ans = 
    '../data/s_element/isdimm_rcv_via_2port_via_minstub.s50p'
ans = 
    '../data/s_element/isdimm_rcv_via_3port_via_minstub.s00p'
>>
```

Trivia:

- `char(10)` gives a newline character because 10 is the ASCII code for newline.
- The `.` character in `regexp` (`regex` in the rest of the coding word) pattern usually does not match a newline, which would make this a safer pattern. [In MATLAB, a dot in `regexp` does match a newline](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#btqhm2s-10), so to disable this, we could add `'dotexceptnewline'` as the last input argument to `regexp``. This is convenient to ensure we don't get the text *outside* of the quotes instead, but not needed since the first match sets precedent.
- Instead of excluding a `'` from the match with `[^'']`, the match can be made non-greedy with `?` as follows, `regexp(txt,'''(.*?)''','tokens')`.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to use textscan:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt','r');
rawdata = textscan(fid,'%s','delimiter','''');
fclose(fid);

output = rawdata{:}(2)
```

As also used in other answers the single apostrophe `'`is represented by a double one: `''`, e.g. for delimiters.

considering the comment:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt','r');
rawdata = textscan(fid,'%s','delimiter','\n');
fclose(fid);

lines = rawdata{1,1};
L = size(lines,1);
output = cell(L,1);
for ii=1:L
    temp = textscan(lines{ii},'%s','delimiter','''');
    output{ii,1} = temp{:}(2);
end
```

Comment: I like this, but then you get a cell array with one column. In a file with multiple such lines how would you find the additional lines?

Answer (score 2):

One easy way is to split the string with single quote delimiter and take the even-numbered strings in the output:

```
str = fileread('test.txt');
out = regexp(str, '''', 'split');
out = out(2:2:end);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using regular expressions. Assuming that there is only one occurrence of text between quotation marks:

```
% select all chars between single quotation marks.
out = regexp(inputString,'''(.*)''','tokens','once');
```

Answer (score 1):

After identifing which lines you want to extract info from, you could tokenize it or do something like this if they all have the same form:

```
test='.model sdata1 s tstonefile=''../data/s_element/isdimm_rcv_via_2port_via_minstub.s50p'' passive=2';
a=strfind(test,'''')
test=test(a(1):a(2))
```